# ASP.NET Enabling Form Fields Based on Radiobox Selection

Tags: asp.net, forms

I currently have this working somewhat as follows

aspRadioButtonList ID="leavingCert" CssClass="radio pc2 top8"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="includeDaft_CheckedChanged">"

But the problem is this refreshes the page is it this possible without refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ASP.NET works; the form posts back to itself. You could add JavaScript logic to toggle the visibility of form fields (in divs) on the client, based on the RadioButtonList selection. In order to do this, you need to remove the server-side-related attributes from your control (the AutoPostBack and the Handler).